# Adding documents to a Many to Many relationship in Mongoose (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, many-to-many

I have a User collection and a Task Collection. Many Users can have many Tasks, and Many Tasks can have many Users. The proper way I believe in doing this is the following models:

```js
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    id: ObjectId,
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    assignments: [ {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Assignment'} ]
});

var TaskSchema = new Schema({
    id: ObjectId,
    title: { type: String, default: '' },
    information: { type: String, default: '' },
    assignments: [ {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Assignment'} ]
});

var AssignmentSchema = new Schema({
    id: ObjectId,
    isCompleted: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    completionDate: { type: Date, default: null },
    tasks: [ {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Task'} ],
    users: [ {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'User'} ]
});
```

If the above models are correct, how do you insert a Task with multiple user assignments? I understand that you would create the Task document first to get its ObjectId, but after that would you just insert all of the assignments into the Assignment collection (with their proper Task and User objectId's) and thats it? Or would I have to insert all of the assignments then edit each individual User and Task to insert the AssignmentId into their assignments property.

I am sure there is a stack over flow question like this already, but I have not been able to find one. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have the answer in your question.

Create a new task, capture the task id. Then find or create a new user, edit or add the task’s id, capture the user id. Add the user id to the task. Repeat for additional users.

I believe this is what you say in the final part of your question?

I don’t see why this cannot work.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be an easier way to do this. like to only have to insert into the Assignments collection then the other ones would update as well with the object ids of that assignment. It seems excessive to make so many edits just for adding one task!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).